# webdav not working after upgrade to 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013-sp1, webdav

We have two CM servers load balanced in our development environment. We upgraded Development environment from 2011 sp1 HR2 to 2013 sp1.

After the upgrade we are able to connect to webdav and browse the folders however we try to create new component or any other operation then it fails with error:

> You do not have the permission

stack trace from event log:

> No items found for WebDAV URL(s):
>   /webdav/400_Publication/Building%20Blocks/.../Test.xml.   Component:
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 512 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.UrlConversion.Convert()    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetTcmUri(String uri)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Session.GetObject(String uri)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.GetSubject(String
>   id, ReadOptions readOptions)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Read(String id,
>   ReadOptions readOptions)    at SyncInvokeRead(Object , Object[] ,
>   Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Please note, I am administrator on Development environment.

Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: Look to Tridion Event log and copy errors from there (with Stack trace).

Comment: Added event log stack trace.

Comment: So which exactly error do you have ?
"No items found for WebDAV"
or
"You do not have the permission" ?
It seems it is different errors (due to different reasons)

Comment: No items found for WebDAV URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the upgrade of 2013 sp1 for webdav to work, following steps have to be performed on client machine which are accessing webdav url

1. Open registry (regedit)
2. Go to location: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> System -> Current ControlSet -> Services -> WebClient -> Parameters
3. Open BasicAuthLevel value to 2.
4. Close the registry
5. Restart the client machine
6. After restarting try to connect to webdav.

It should work! :)